# ICU, Unicode and libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unicode, icu

My goal is to implement Unicode in UTF-16 format in an embedded system. I want to be able to use multiple languages to display on my LCD. The texts in multiple languages are going to be written in separate text files.
I usually program with Eclipse with a GCC compiler.

I've done some research about Unicode and it seems that ICU holds good libraries to get Unicode working on embedded systems.
The ICU version I've downloaded is written for Windows Visual Studio 10. I'm fairly new to this program so bear with me..
I've installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 to compile ICU and changed the library path as mentioned in the readme file.
When trying to run the cintltst im getting the following error:

```
#### Note:  ICU Init without build-specific setDataDirectory() failed.
U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR
#### ERROR! C:\Documents\ICU\source\test\cintltst\.\x86\Debug\cintltst.exe: u_init() failed with status = "U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR".
*** Check the ICU_DATA environment variable and
*** check that the data files are present.
*** Exiting.  Use the '-w' option if data files were
*** purposely removed, to continue test anyway.
```

Now a couple of questions:

1) I don't know what file the ICU is expecting, or even what I should expect to be a proper output.

2) Do I need to include a library of Unicode in some form?

3) If I'm able to run this sample program, should I change anything prior to copying the needed files into my own software?

4) The software shows me that failure of this check is normal when ICU data is not packaged into a shared library. Does this mean I need to package the ICU data somehow?

I think it could be something in the settings of Visual Studio which is not correct.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you have the ICU_DATA environment variable set? And do you have the data files it claims it needs?

Comment: The icudt54.dll libraries are located in C:\Documents\ICU\bin. I don't see any .dat files in the same folder for the data libraries. The project path environment variable has been set to PATH=C:\Documents\ICU\bin;%PATH%
$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment) in the project settings. Am I still missing something here?

Comment: Make sure the data library is around 20mb not 40k. There’s a stub version built for bootstrapping. See the readme and the .bat file in the allinone dir

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error for cintltst (U_FILE_ACCESS_ERROR) after building ICU with Visual Studio for platform x64. Then I tried again building for platform Win32 and that worked.

Comment: Maybe the data build failed the first time.